# Como passar um valor de Javascript, para um formulário PHP, e enviar como método POST?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Como passar um valor de Javascript para um formulário PHP e enviar como método POST?

Tenho um script:

```
if (cc.isValid()) { 
    $('#debug').text(cc.hash());             
    var verifica = cc.hash();
    //  $('#debug').text(verifica);      
    console.log(verifica);

    alert('Pegou o verifica: '+verifica)
}
```

Preciso pegar o valor de "verifica" e enviar junto a um formulário HTML + PHP como método POST este valor do Javascript. Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para se fazer isso com Java puro faça o seguinte:

Crie um input do tipo hidden no seu formulário php:

```
<form name='form01' method='post' action='index.php'>
.
.
<input type='hidden' name='valoremjavascript' id='valoremjavascript'>
.
.
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("valoremjavascript").value = variaveljavascript;
</script>
```

No script java você adiciona o valor da variável no formulário:

Se enviar o furmulário depois de ter executado o script Java, o formulário terá o valor contido em variaveljavascript.

Answer (score 2):

Crie um `input` tipo `hidden` no formulário (em qualquer lugar dentro do seu `<form></form>`) com o `name` "verifica":

```
<input type="hidden" name="verifica">
```

Com o seu jQuery você altera o `value` do `input` com o valor da variável:

```
if (cc.isValid()) { 
   $('#debug').text(cc.hash());             
   var verifica = cc.hash();
   //  $('#debug').text(verifica);      
   console.log(verifica);
   alert('Pegou o verifica: '+verifica)

   // insere o valor no campo
   $("input[name='verifica']").val(verifica);

   // ou
   // $("[name='verifica']").val(verifica);
```

Desta forma ao submeter o formulário, irá junto o campo com o valor adicionado.

Comment: Deu certo. Muito obrigado.